# Parse data from html response

Tags: angular, typescript, parsing

I'm sending a `GET` request to a `WMS` service through angular's `HttpClient`. The response what I get is a html in string. How can I parse data from this string?

The response looks like this:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
<body>
<p>Temperature 16.6 °C</p>
<p>Temperature 18.2 °C</p>
</body></html>
```

I need to get the values inside the paragraph tags. I found solutions only to display data through `innerHtml` directive, but this is not my case.

**EDIT:**

I found one possible solution through `DOMParser`:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(myHtmlStringResponse, "text/html");
const values = [];

const p = doc.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (const item of Array.from(p)) {
     values.push(item.textContent);
}
```

Comment: [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) is the simple and robust answer to this question, whereas stripping HTML is an arbitrary answer which may only work in specific circumstances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strip all the html from the response with this regEx:

```
data.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
```

where data is your response string

You will get this:

```
Temperature 16.6 °C
Temperature 18.2 °C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parse through using tag name.

```
var pele = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i=0;i< pele.length;i++) {
  console.log(pele[i].innerHTML)
}
```

But make sure if you are using jquery then put this code snippet under ready function.